# Change font size in a loop to fit height

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

I'm trying to reduce font-size in a Bootstrap carousel when its height's container is taller than 150px.

```
<div class="carousel-item">
 <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
  <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
 </div>
</div>


$('#crsPos3,#crsPos4').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
        fixFontSize($(this)); 
})    

function fixFontSize(obj) {
        $(obj).find('h3').each(function () {
            a = $(this).find('a');
            var i = 0;
            while ($(this).outerHeight() > 150 && i < 1000) {
                var fs = parseInt($(a).css('font-size'));
                fs = (fs - 1) + 'px';
                $(a).css('font-size', fs);
                console.log($(obj).attr('id') + ' ' + fs);
                i=i+1;
            }
        });
    }
```

I use var i to avoid overload, but it reduces only 1 pixel each time.
Console shows (1000) crsPos4 21px

Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Some possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+font+height+to+fit

Comment: Your [code appears to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/0uqxkf4e/). Could it be that something else happens after the `slid.bs.carousel` event fires?  Add an alert at the end of your `fixFontSize` to halt processing to see what your code has done and then see if anything changes after that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Maybe, the jquery function .css is asynchronous and that's why div didn't change its height. Adding a pause to recall the function works:

```
function fixFontSize(obj) {
$(obj).find('h3').each(function () {
if ($(this).outerHeight() > 150) { 
$(this).find('a').css({ fontSize: function (i, v) { return parseInt(v) - 1; } }); setTimeout(function () { fixFontSize(obj); }, 10); } }); }
```